# Convert PHP variable for Flash object

Tags: php, flash, clipboard

I'm trying to use a copy to clipboard feature whereby the link copied is a link to a specific post.

The PHP variable for this is `<?php echo $pinDetails->pin_url?>`

I am using Clippy and the object code is:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
width="110"
height="14"
id="clippy" >
<param name="movie" value="/scripts/clippy-master/build/clippy.swf"/>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param NAME="FlashVars" value="<?php echo $pinDetails->pin_url?>">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#">
<embed src="/scripts/clippy-master/build/clippy.swf"
width="110"
           height="14"
           name="clippy"
           quality="high"
           allowScriptAccess="always"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
           FlashVars="<?php echo $pinDetails->pin_url?>"
           bgcolor="#"
    />
</object>
```

As you can see, my inserted variable are there. But when testing they produce a literal copy of "pin_url?>" instead of the variable details.

how can I amend this to work?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is installed on your server? And that the file extension is `.php`?

Comment: Yes, I use php for my website.